# Binding data with values from a listener in angular

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am creating a chome app using Angular.
I am expermineting with the Bluetooth api which has an event listener being triggered when the bluetooth adapter is set on or off.

I am showing the values from the adapter object in html with `{{ powered }} {{ discovering }} and {{ available }}`
It works fine but I am not sure this is the way to go in Angular

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('BluetoothController', function($scope){

chrome.bluetooth.onAdapterStateChanged.addListener(  
function(adapter) {
    $scope.powered=adapter.powered;
    $scope.discovering=adapter.discovering;
    $scope.available=adapter.available;
    $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

Is working with `$scope.apply()` the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks great. The only thing is I would probably put it in a service (for reusability) or a directive (if you made a reusable bluetooth widget). If you make a service I bet other people would be interested in using it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's my first Chrome App and my first Angular app so I will figure out how to make a service later. When everything works :)